# Get only the in stock simple products of a configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, stock

I am trying to get all the in stock simple products of a configurable product in magento2.

Below code gets *all in stock and out of stock products of configurable product*, But I need only the in stock products

```
$configProduct = $this->_product->load($currentProduct->getId());
$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
```

**How can we filter this by in stock?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Model StockRegistry **Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry $stockRegistry**

Register a Block or Helper. My code example use Helper.

```
class Data
{
    protected $catalogProduct;
    protected $stockRegistry;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry $stockRegistry)
    {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
    }

    /**
     * @param $product
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product[]
     */
    public function getAllowProducts($product)
    {

            $skipSaleableCheck = $this->catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck();

            $products = $skipSaleableCheck ?
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product, null) :
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getSalableUsedProducts($product, null);
        return $products;
    }

    public function getChildInStock($product)
    {
        $inStock = [];
        foreach ($this->getAllowProducts($product) as $_product) {
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(), 1);
            $saleable = $stockItem->getIsInStock() && $this->verifyStock($stockItem);
            if($saleable){
                $inStock[] = $_product;
            }
        }
        return $inStock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use some children also

```
foreach($_children as $child)
{
   $childproduct= $this->_product->load($child->getId());
}
```